# How to drop rows based on column value if column is not set as index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list and a dataframe which look like this:

```
list = ['a', 'b']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'B':[9, 9, 8, 4]})
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
df1 = df.drop([x for x in list])
```

I am getting the following error message:

"KeyError: "['a' 'b'] not found in axis""

I know I can do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'B':[9, 9, 8, 4]}).set_index('A')
df1 = df.drop([x for x in list])
```

How can I drop the list values without having to set column 'A' as index? My dataframe has multiple columns.

Comment: Use a filter `df[~df.A.isin(list)]`

Comment: 1: Do not use a list name as `list` as it will override the default `list` 2: use `isin` with invert as suggested above by @Psidom which is better than the suggested solutions

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct axis, namely `axis=1`.

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

> axis{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0. Whether to drop labels from the index (0 or ‘index’) or columns (1 or ‘columns’).

You also need to make sure you are using the correct column names, (ie. uppercase rather than lower case. And you should avoid using python reserved names, so don't use `list`.

This should work:

```
myList = ['A', 'B']
df1 = df.drop([x for x in myList], axis=1)
```

Comment: I thought he wanted to drop a,b from column A. Not the entire column. But who knows..

Comment: sorry but this doesnt work. please see Marios comment

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
    A   B
0   a   9
1   b   9
2   c   8
3   d   4
```

Code:

```
for i in list:
  ind = df[df['A']==i].index.tolist() 
  df=df.drop(ind)
df
```

Output:

```
    A   B
2   c   8
3   d   4
```